# When should System.Type be inherited

Tags: .net, reflection, system.type

The documentation for [Type.GetTypeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecode.aspx) states:

> **Remarks**
>
> When you inherit from [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx), you can change the behavior of this method
>   by overriding the [GetTypeCodeImpl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecodeimpl.aspx) method.

The documentation not describe *when* to inherit from System.Type. Is it even valid or applicable for any real application or is it only for implementers of CLI?

The [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) documentation doesn't contain this information either, it only has a list of which members must be overridden for derived classes.

As there is no way of overriding `typeof`, I assume that the `typeof` operator still return an instance of the internal System.RuntimeType class from the mscorlib assembly, or similar. What use would then a user derived class have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't derive your own type from `System.Type`, basically. It's not something I can *ever* see a use for, unless you're part of the CLR team. It's just about possible that if you're implementing a mocking framework or something like that, there *could* be some reason to do so - but I'm pretty doubtful. I'd be pretty suspicious of anything deriving from `Type` - I would expect it's the kind of thing which can go wrong fairly easily if you're not careful.

I suspect what the documentation *should* have said was "classes deriving from `System.Type` change the behaviour of this method by overriding `GetTypeCodeImpl`" - although frankly even that is something that *users* don't really need to know.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to create instances and classes I would create on the fly at run time (from a data source ex: XML). I successfully subclassed System.Type but it was useless: you can’t create instances using Activator.CreateInstance(yourSubType).

I got over the problem by converting my source (XML) into compilable c# code and then compile it using CSharpCodeProvider.